# Can I use javascript to write xml files, or will I have to learn php/asp/mysql/something else?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, dom

I understand this question has been asked before, but I couldn't think of a simple definition of my problem to put in it's place.  I am learning to do this informally, so I'm not exactly sure how to phrase questions/search for answers yet.

I'm trying to build a simple checklist program as I learn javascript - I'm doing this by hand without using any libraries (so no jQuery, just basic javascript).  I have a functioning DOM interface getting formatted by CSS, all running in and editing the contents of a `<div>`, so that side of things seems fine.
I'm testing this off of my HDD and have no intention of hosting it anywhere.

Currently, I'm trying to solve my data storage problem without installing php/mysql/apache.  I'd like to have each task list nested "subtasks" when selected, with one level of nesting.
To do this I'd like to create a new XML file every time I create a new task, and then append it's information to a list file (list.xml) so that I can navigate list.xml to dynamically display all the current primary tasks.
I've since learned that you cannot simply create new .xml files with javascript alone, for security reasons.  While this makes sense, I'm now looking for other solutions.

What is the simplest way to store this information as it's entered?  One solution I've considered is having just one XML file (so I always know what to point the script to), and using "`<id>`" nodes to slave subtasks to their respective primaries.  This would, however, create a very long and disorganized XML file that would become cumbersome and annoying to traverse, forcing me to write a tricky method for looping through it.

Should I continue as I am to simply complete the project and help lock in my skills (it will be my first complete "program" with a gui of any kind that wasn't dictated by a guide or lesson), or should I bite the bullet and go through the annoying php install (I did this on my last tower and it was a frustrating time-consuming mess) and learn php/mysql/apache for all the server-side nonsense?

sry about tl;dr please help my pynchonesque code masters will kill me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're learning Javascript, I'd recommend staying with Javascript (don't jump over to PHP or some such just because it'll save you 5 minutes in configuration).

There are a number of really nice Javascript serverside frameworks that will happily write files to the file system or talk to a database for you. Node.js is currently the most popular.  I don't want to start a flame war about how or why Node is superior to PHP, I'm simply saying that if you're a beginner, I wouldn't mix apples and oranges and just stay within one language.

Comment: I'm going to look into Node.js more deeply than I have, but the first first impression I got of it was that it was it's own language (despite the .js indicating otherwise).  I would have marked this as the answer because I agree with the sentiment about staying within one language, but I understand the syntax for php fairly well and was mainly worried about installing it.  Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Node.js is not a language. It is a framework, which is written 100% in javascript!  If you're comfortable with PHP and feel it's the right tool for the job... by all means, have at it.  I was simply suggesting that you would have an easier time sticking to one language.  Personally, as I know both languages quite well, I find working with them both simultaneously VERY annoying because they have just enough similarity in syntax for me to constantly step on my own toes... typing var in PHP and adding unnecessary $ to my Javascript vars and then having to edit (and so forth).

Comment: you may also want to read this: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Comment: well, I have XAMPP installed and working (and secure!) now, so I'm figuring I'll just use jQuery (I gave in...) and an sql database, and avoid php as much as possible for now.  Thanks for the link, I'll peruse it presently (is that a "deal with it" evee favicon o_O ?).  Thanks for your responses by the way, while using XAMPP is future proofing, you've been giving me a lot of insight

Comment: SWEET CHRIST.  I got as far as the operators section, and saw how PHP handles == vs === relative to variable vs objects and stopped reading.  I'll be using as little of that as I have to until I'm finished learning javascript and can focus on a server side language that's NOT PHP O_O

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much in web programming with only user side. Sooner or later  you will have to learn also server side. And installing PHP is not so annoying. You can use [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) server. It has very simple installation.

Comment: I haven't read the entire question but PHP is indeed a 5 minute install using WAMP or XAMPP.

Comment: Installing PHP might not be annoying, but *using* it on the other hand ..

Comment: @pst! bravo. I didn't want to say the same thing because I don't like the kinds of conversations that these opinions produce, but I like the cut of your jib.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation for wamp/xampp.  XAMPP specifically looks good.  Last time I tried installing it I ran into having to install cygwin and got path errors in cmd and oh god it was A Thing.